# Error when running my jar with arguments

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, jar, executable-jar

I have a spark application packaged with maven. At run-time, I have to give 3 arguments (paths of 3 files to create RDDs). So I used spark-submit command as the officiel website of spark indicates:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--class <main-class> \
--master <master-url> \
--deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
--conf <key>=<value> \
.. # other options
<application-jar> \
[application-arguments]
```

My submit-command looks like:

```
 \bin\spark-submit --class myapp.Main --master local[*] file:///C:\Users\pc\Desktop\eclipse\myapp\target\myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ["C:\Users\pc\Desktop\pathToFile1.csv", "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\pathToFile2.csv", "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\pathToFile3.csv"]
```

I moddified my Main class  as follows to get paths at runtime:

```
String pathToFile1=args[0];
String pathToFile2=args[1];
String pathToFile3=args[2];
```

But I get an error message that says that the specified path does not exist. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you should have`[` and `]` in the command. Usually those indicate optional values.

Comment: no i am not sure i just follow the officiel website, and what does mean optional values?

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

@bradimus you were right i dont have to use [], i have to write it as :

```
 \bin\spark-submit --class myapp.Main --master local[*] file:///C:\Users\pc\Desktop\eclipse\myapp\target\myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar C:\Users\pc\Desktop\pathToFile1.csv C:\Users\pc\Desktop\pathToFile2.csv C:\Users\pc\Desktop\pathToFile3.csv
```